# Unauthorized bluemail

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, httpsurlconnection

Good morning, I'm trying to use bluemail on dedicated bluemix.
When I do the HttpsURLConnection and I want to do a mail sending via mail, I throws a getResponseCode = 401 and getResponseMessage = Unauthorized.

I'm trying out all the possible ways but it always tells me the same thing.

How does this work?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Wagego, unfortunately, your question is not clear and is likely to be closed.  Please see the help center for more information on writing good StackOverflow questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Bluemail is an internal service and you should leverage the internal Bluemix Dedicated support channels.